# Model learns with SGD but not Adam

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, adam, sgd

I was going through a basic PyTorch MNIST example [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py) and noticed that when I changed the optimizer from SGD to Adam the model did not converge. Specifically, I changed line 106 from

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr, momentum=args.momentum)
```

to

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)
```

I thought this would have no effect on the model. With SGD the loss quickly dropped to low values after about a quarter of an epoch. However with Adam, the loss did not drop at all even after 10 epochs. I'm curious to why this is happening; it seems to me these should have nearly identical performance.

I ran this on Win10/Py3.6/PyTorch1.01/CUDA9

And to save you a tiny bit of code digging, here are the hyperparams:

- lr=0.01
- momentum=0.5
- batch_size=64

Answer (score 5):

Adam is famous for working out of the box with its *default* paremeters, which, in almost all frameworks, include a learning rate of 0.001 (see the default values in [Keras](https://keras.io/optimizers/), [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/adam.html), and [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer)), which is indeed the value suggested in the [Adam paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980).

So, I would suggest changing to

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

or simply

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
```

in order to leave `lr` in its default value (although I would say I am surprised, as MNIST is famous nowadays for working practically with whatever you may throw into it).